# Mobile secure login system?

Tags: security, mobile, authentication

I want clients to be able to login into their account from an iOS application. 
Is there a good way on doing this in a secure way?
Sure I'd submit the password as a hashed value, but wouldn't there still be the possibility of someone to spoof my clients credentials?

The only credentials provided by the client are an email address and a password.
A secret key would be possible, but that wouldn't be too secure as I'd have to hardcode this key into every delivered copy of the application and someone could possibly decompile and see the secret.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSL/TLS and hardcode the public key(or at least the fingerprint) of the server in your client. That way you can check if the server is the correct server.

And since you use asymmetric cryptography you don't need to embed the private key of the server into the client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not have a SSL connection I'm afraid. 
Can you give me a coded example on how to encrypt data (with puplic key) and then decrypt it again (using the private key on the server)?

Comment: You don't encrypt the data itself, but you just use the asymmetric keys to exchange a random symmetric key, and then encrypt the data with that symmetric key. But designing a good cryptographic protocol is *hard* and best left to professionals. Why can't you run SSL ontop of your TCP connection?

Comment: I found out what to do now... I saw this [iOS OpenSSL library](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) and would like to do something similar to the PHP function [`openssl_seal`](http://at2.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php). Is there a function in iOS that works like this?
If I could seal the data with the public key, I could send it securely and then `openssl_open` it on the server. Any suggestions?